# return (int32_t& 1u) ^ 1u mean?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
class GameTree {
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        int32_t value;
        uint32_t depth;
        Node* father;
        set<Node*> children;
        uint8_t cntX, cntY;
        uint8_t board[15][15]{};

        Node() {
            father = nullptr;
            children.clear();
            value = INT32_MIN;
            depth = cntX = cntY = 0;
            memset(board, 0, sizeof(board));//初始化数组
        }

        Node(Node* node, uint8_t opeX, uint8_t opeY) {
            depth = node->depth + 1;
            value = is_max_node() ? INT32_MIN : INT32_MAX;
            father = node;
            children.clear();
            cntX = opeX;
            cntY = opeY;
            memcpy(board, node->board, sizeof(board));
            board[cntX][cntY] = (depth & 1u) ? 'B' : 'W';
        }

        bool is_max_node() {
            return (depth & 1u) ^ 1u;
        }
```

I want to know that what this line mean  `return (depth & 1u) ^ 1u`;
And  what `board[cntX][cntY] = (depth & 1u) ? 'B' : 'W';` is mean?
I can't understand that & and ^ mean in these code;
Is `&` mean and ,`^` mean or?
hope Someone can help me !

Comment: Lookup bitwise operations

Comment: It's a very obfuscated way of writing `depth % 2 == 0`.